How can I modify the cypress selector to only highlight the buttons that have "COVID" in the category?
This selector:
cy.get('.mat-mdc-row[data-canedit="true"]:has(.mat-column-categories>span) .mat-column-actions button[id^=actionMenu]')

highlights all 4 buttons in the far-right column. How can I modify it to where only the buttons in the same row as the "COVID-19-Resume" category get selected.
I tried
.mat-mdc-row[data-canedit="true"]:has(.mat-column-categories>span:contains("COVID")) .mat-column-actions button[id^=actionMenu]

But that showed 0 results.


To find the row that has "Covid" in the second column, use td:nth-child(2):contains("Covid").
To illustrate, here's a similar test on the Material Angular examples page.

it('get last column of a row with particular value in Name column', () => {

  cy.visit('https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples');

  cy.get('table-basic-example').within(() => {

    cy.get('tr:has( td:nth-child(2):contains("Lithium") )')
      .find('td:last')
      .should('have.text', ' Li ')
  })
})


You have more than one Category with "Covid", so I recommend adding :first as well,
cy.get('tr:has( td:nth-child(2):contains("Covid"):first )')
  .find('td:last')
  .click()


You can use cy.contains() to get the row containing "Covid-19". After that, chain the .find() command to obtain the button within that row.
cy.contains('tr.mat-mdc-row', 'Covid-19')
  .find('td.mat-column-actions button[id^=actionMenu]')

As already mentioned there are two rows matching, so you could filter on another text column such as "SPRINGBOOT"
cy.contains('tr.mat-mdc-row', 'Covid-19')              // locates 2 rows
  .filter(':contains(SPRINGBOOT)')                      // filter to 1 row
  .find('td.mat-column-actions button[id^=actionMenu]')  // find the button

